# Copying a file from a DVD to Hard Disk

Tags: command-line, files

How do I copy a file/folder from a DVD to my hard drive using the Terminal?

Comment: What sort of DVD are you attempting to copy?  Is this a video disc?  A data disc?

Comment: Dear Stephen Michael , I have got a GNOME DVD but do not how to install the same into the Hard Disk. Can you kindly help with a suitable procedure. Thanks! anil

Comment: @KasiyA read OP's last comment. "... do not know how to install the same.."

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you try to do. If you have a DVD mounted (check e.g. by typing "mount" into a terminal to get a list) You can copy any file from there to your harddisk by using the cp command in a terminal or by using the file manager of your choice.

If you mean by "GNOME DVD" Ubuntu live or desktop DVD and want to install Ubuntu onto your harddrive, there should be an icon on the desktop after having booted into the live session, which will start up ubiquity and commence with a regular installation.

If you have the deb package files of Gnome on a DVD, for what ever reason, and want to install it into an existing Ubuntu system, dpkg should be able to do that.

Please give us some more details.